# Pass EJS Dynamic Template String into Express CSS File For Dynamic Background Image in an HTML Element

Tags: css, express, templates, dynamic, ejs

I have a working css file for my Express ejs web app.  All styles are working fine, paths are fine, etc.

In one ejs file I essentially have this:

```
<%- include ("partials/header") %>
<img src= <%= project.image1 %> width="300px">
<%- include ("partials/footer") %>
```

The image referred to by project.image1 works perfectly.

Can I do this in my css file:

```
.class {
background-image: url("<%= project.image1 %>");
}
```

I looked through the possibly-duplicate questions and as far as I could tell none of them were relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's only work with the `style` in the same file and not working for `link` style. **For an example** you can look at this code below:

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

let image = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/gd-wagtail-prod-assets/images/evolving_google_identity_2x.max-4000x2000.jpegquality-90.jpg';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  res.render('home', { image } );
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is up on port 3000'));
```

> The code above only a simple example server with express

**home.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- it's not working with this -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- it's only working with this -->
  <style>
    .my-background {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      /* this is my ejs variable: image */
      background-image: url('<%= image %>'); 
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-size: 100px;
      background-position: left;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="my-background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you, Titus Sutio Fanpula! I see that an external .css stylesheet is the problem.  In this case I should have no problem using an inline style tag as per your example. I will give it a try.(I voted your helpful answer up, but am of such low stature it doesn't register.)